# python tornado logging library

Tags: python-3.x, logging, tornado

How do we log the http request PATH, arguments, method type and response status, response content (if any) for requests in python `Tornado` web framework?
One approach is to hook into `prepare` method to add the custom logging as required. Was wondering if there is any python library already providing such a logging mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Tornado can automatically configure the Python standard logging system to output all this information. The easiest way to enable it is with:

```
import tornado.options

tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

If you add that to the [Tornado "getting started" example](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html) and visit http://localhost:8888 in your browser, it logs:

```
[I 151113 10:48:27 web:1932] 200 GET / (::1) 1.54ms
[W 151113 10:48:27 web:1932] 404 GET /favicon.ico (::1) 1.52ms
```

You'll notice on my system that Chrome uses IPv6 by default, so its source address is "[::1]", and that Chrome tries to access favicon.ico, which the example server does not have.